# Uncertainty on covariance

Tags: covariance, uncertainty

I think this is an easy question but I didn't find any convincing answer yet:

In an experiment I have made two sets of measurements for two random variables $X$ and $Y$:

$$X=(x_1,...,x_N)$$
$$Y=(y_1,...,y_N)$$

I also have standard error vectors for each sample:

$$\Delta X=(\Delta x_1,...,\Delta x_N)$$
$$\Delta Y=(\Delta y_1,...,\Delta y_N)$$

The unbiased convariance is given by:

$$cov(X,Y)=\frac{N}{N-1}(\overline{XY}-\overline{X}\ \overline{Y})$$

What is the uncertainty on this unbiased covariance ?

$X$, $Y$ are not independent.